# Implementation of encryption algorithm using Lambda UDF

Tags: lambda, aws-glue

I have a LAMBDA UDF which has the logic to encrypt and decrypt my sensitive columns. As part of the data pipeline, I use RedShift external function to call the lambda UDF to encrypt/decrypt the column for transformations within RedShift. I also have to do some transformations in S3 using Glue Job. My question is, is it possible to call the Lambda UDF from Glue job to encrypt and decrypt or should I create a Glue UDF and replicate the encrypt/decrypt logic in the Glue UDF. And then use the Glue UDF to encrypt and decrypt from glue jobs.

Thanks